# Less: Easiest way to add font-weight to font-family variables

Tags: html, css, fonts, less

I'm working on a system that uses LESS for styling. The variables for the font families look like this:

```
@font-family-regular: "robotoregular", sans-serif;
@font-family-bold: "robotobold", sans-serif;
@font-family-condensedregular: "roboto_condensedregular", sans-serif;
@font-family-condensedbold: "roboto_condensedbold", sans-serif;
```

Now I have to change the font family to Arial. I'm going to use Arial Narrow for the condensed fonts:

```
@font-family-regular: Arial, sans-serif;
@font-family-bold: Arial, sans-serif;
@font-family-condensedregular: "Arial Narrow", sans-serif;
@font-family-condensedbold: "Arial Narrow", sans-serif;
```

The problem is, that I can't set the font weight of the two bold font styles that way. I could add "font-weight: bold;" manually to all styles that use one of the bold families, but I would like to avoid that.

Is there a way to tell LESS something like "for all elements: if font-family is set to @font-family-bold or @font-family-condensedbold add font-weight: bold;" or something like that? What would be the most elegant solution?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Just on word: Mixins.

Answer (score 0):

I fear you'll have to change the markup a little bit after all, but this is a solution i can offer, that might work for you:

```
@font-family-regular: "robotoregular", sans-serif;
@font-family-bold: "robotobold", sans-serif;
@font-family-condensedregular: "roboto_condensedregular", sans-serif;
@font-family-condensedbold: "roboto_condensedbold", sans-serif;

.font-face-bold (@font-select) when 
    (@font-select = @font-family-bold),
    (@font-select = @font-family-condensedbold) {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.font-face (@size, @font-select) {
    font: @size @font-select;
    .font-face-bold(@font-select);
}


// USAGE
.my-class {
    .font-face(14px, @font-family-regular);
}

.my-bold-class {
    .font-face(14px, @font-family-bold);
}

.my-condensed-class {
  .font-face(14px, @font-family-condensedregular);
}

.my-condensed-bold-class {
  .font-face(14px, @font-family-condensedbold);
}
```

What i do here is that i create two mixins that are nested in one another. The inner one is conditional and only "does" something if the passed variable is either `@font-family-bold` or `@font-family-condensedbold`.

Here is a [Live Example](http://less2css.org/#%7B%22less%22%3A%22%40font-family-regular%3A%20%5C%22robotoregular%5C%22%2C%20sans-serif%3B%5Cn%40font-family-bold%3A%20%5C%22robotobold%5C%22%2C%20sans-serif%3B%5Cn%40font-family-condensedregular%3A%20%5C%22roboto_condensedregular%5C%22%2C%20sans-serif%3B%5Cn%40font-family-condensedbold%3A%20%5C%22roboto_condensedbold%5C%22%2C%20sans-serif%3B%5Cn%5Cn.font-face-bold%20(%40font-select)%20when%20%5Cn%5Ct(%40font-select%20%3D%20%40font-family-bold)%2C%5Cn%5Ct(%40font-select%20%3D%20%40font-family-condensedbold)%20%7B%5Cn%20%20font-weight%3A%20bold%3B%5Cn%7D%5Cn%5Cn.font-face%20(%40size%2C%20%40font-select)%20%7B%5Cn%5Ctfont%3A%20%40size%20%40font-select%3B%5Cn%20%20%20%20.font-face-bold(%40font-select)%3B%5Cn%7D%5Cn%5Cn%5Cn%2F%2F%20USAGE%5Cn.my-class%20%7B%5Cn%5Ct.font-face(14px%2C%20%40font-family-regular)%3B%5Cn%7D%5Cn%5Cn.my-bold-class%20%7B%5Cn%5Ct.font-face(14px%2C%20%40font-family-bold)%3B%5Cn%7D%5Cn%5Cn.my-condensed-class%20%7B%5Cn%20%20.font-face(14px%2C%20%40font-family-condensedregular)%3B%5Cn%7D%5Cn%5Cn.my-condensed-bold-class%20%7B%5Cn%20%20.font-face(14px%2C%20%40font-family-condensedbold)%3B%5Cn%7D%22%7D) of the code above.

Hopefully this works for you.